# AutoHotKey: How to move the position of the progress bar

Tags: autohotkey

I have a working progress bar, and wanted to move it to top left corner of the screen. I used `x0 y0 w300` to control the position and size.

But doing so my `%progress_bar_percentage%` stopped updating. I want to ask, is it possible to have the position and progress bar % working at the same time?

```
a = %counter%
b = %CaseArrayCount%
progress_bar_percentage := Round(((a/b) * 100), 2)

; Draw the progress bar on the screen
Progress, x0 y0 w300, %progress_bar_percentage%, %progress_bar_percentage%`%, System Processing , Sample APP
```

Reference: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Progress.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation actually says that `options` can only be used if the progress window does not yet exist.

> If the progress window does not exist: A new progress window is
>   created (replacing any old one), and Param1 is a string of zero or
>   more options from the list below.

That means you can only set the position in the very beginning when creating the progress bar window:

```
Progress, x0 y0, 0`%, System Processing , Sample APP

Loop, 100 {
    Progress, %A_Index%, %A_Index%`%, System Processing , Sample APP
    Sleep, 100
}
```

If you try to use options within the loop, you'll see the progress window being destroyed and newly created with every iteration and the progress value is ignored. According to the documentation `if Param1 is an pure number, its bar's position is changed to that value`, so you can't actually do both options and progress value at the same time.

Without hacks, the best thing you could do is probably:

```
Loop, 10 {
    value := A_Index*10
    Progress, x%value% y%value%, %A_Index%`%, System Processing , Sample APP
    Progress, % value, % value "%", System Processing , Sample APP
    Sleep, 1000
}
```

Comment: You just saved my life :) +1. Thank you!